# Apply K-means for Scala to each element of rdd.

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I have a big rdd in spark scala, where each element is array from arrays.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize[array1[array1_1[], array1_2[], ....array1_24]], .... , array240[array240_1[], array240_2[], ....array240_24]]
```

All elements are different and I should apply k-means algorithm to each of them.

But, k-means in Spark works only with RDDs - not arrays.

So, I do next

```
for (i <= 0 to 240) {

    val rdd = sc.parallelize[array1[array1_1[], array1_2[], ....array1_24]]]
```

But it is too slow...

I have cluster from 5 big nodes and they can do more...

How can I solve my problem without for loop?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a serious design problem here.

- if each array is small enough to be efficiently handled locally on a single partition there is nothing to gain by using Spark MLlib. Just use your favorite not distributed machine learning library to train K-means on each item individually. With large cluster and small data Spark will spend most of time just passing messages around.
- if this is not the case then using arrays to store data like this doesn't makes sense. Either each sample should be a separate RDD or these can be combined but flattened with labels.

Based on your description it looks like this is the first case. If against all reason you want to use MLLib then try to significantly reduce parallelism for each RDD and build your jobs spearately depending on a scheduler to do the rest.

Comment: I can only emphasize that running k-means is *cheap* and you do not need distributed computation for this at all; tools such as ELKI have very very fast k-means implementations and will likely be *much* faster **as long as the data fits into main memory**.